# Benutzt man immer einen Wasserschlauch in einer Wasserschlacht?

Tags: meaning

Ich suche ein Wort für das Kinderspiel, in dem sich Kinder mit Wasser bekriegen. *Wasserschlacht* klingt gut, aber mein Wörterbuch merkt an, dass es ein Krieg "mit einem Wasserschlauch" sei. Ist das wahr? Gibt es ein besseres Wort?

Comment: Nur ein paar kleine Anmerkungen zur Frage: "wo Kinder kriegen mit Wasser" ist zwar (denke ich, aber bin keine Experte) grammatikalisch korrekt, aber bei "Kinder kriegen" denkt man automatisch an Babies. ;-)  "wo sich Kinder mit Wasser bekriegen" ist besser, klingt aber militärischer als eine Wasserschlacht tatsächlich ist.  Und "Wörterbuch anmerkt" (das t ist bestimmt ein Tippfehler) müsste "Wörterbuch merkt an" (oder "bemerkt").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Wasserschlacht" ist definitiv in Ordnung und das gebräuchlichste Wort dafür.

Eine Wasserschlacht kann, aber *muss* nicht mit einem Wasserschlauch geführt werden.

Comment: +1, allerdings "muß" sollte "muss" geschrieben werden - laut neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung (die übrigens gar nicht mehr *so* neu ist). :)

Comment: @splattne das ist ein wichtiges Thema. Habe eine Meta-Frage gestartet: [Which spelling standard(s) to use? Alte oder neue Rechtschreibung?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/11)

Answer (score 12):

Wasserschlacht ist korrekt. Hierzu wird nicht unbedingt ein Wasserschlauch benötigt, sondern sie kann auch mit Wasserballons (Wasserbomben, d. h. Luftballons oder Plastiktüten, die mit Wasser gefüllt sind), Eimern, Wasserspritzpistolen und ähnlichem stattfinden.

Answer (score 5):

Spritzpistolen und Wasserbomben (mit Wasser gefüllte Luftballons) eignen sich ebenfalls hervorragend.